# Analyticity of Covering Maps

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-surfaces, covering-spaces

Let $\mathbb{D}$ be the unit disc, $Y$ be a Riemann surface and $\pi:\mathbb{D}\longrightarrow Y$ be a universal covering map. Suppose that $\pi$ is not given explicitly. Under what conditions can it be deduced that $\pi$ is a local biholomorphism?

Alternatively, let $U\subset \mathbb{D}$ be a single sheet of $\pi$. Under what conditions is $\pi\mid_U$ holomorphic?

Obviously, $\pi$ is proper and a local homeomorphism. I'm wondering if there are any results (or else, any insightful observations) that may establish conditions under which $\pi$ must be locally holomorphic as well.

For context, the question arose while constructing a proof of Picard's Big Theorem using some results in Riemann Surface theory. Toward the end, I realized that being able to establish analyticity of an arbitrary covering map would be a powerful tool, but I couldn't find any results in Forster or Jost (maybe because it's unfeasible, but I'd like to think that there is at least a weak result).

Comment: What sort of conditions are you interested in?  Certainly $\pi$ will usually not be holomorphic.

Comment: It seems you are essentially asking when a local homeomorphism will be holomorphic, but these are very, *very* different conditions in general. Is there some context for this in which the two might be more related?

Comment: Sorry, I guess the question was extremely vague. I've edited it to include more context.

Comment: There are no nontrivial finite-sheeted coverings from the unit disk.

Comment: Can you reformulate in this context : as a (simply connected) Riemann surface the [universal cover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniformization_theorem) $\bar{Y}$ is constructed as the set of curves $\in Y$ with basepoint $p_0$ modulo homotopy (ie. $\alpha = \beta$ if $\alpha \cup \beta_-$ is a closed loop and it is trivial in $\pi_1(Y)$). The difficulty is to show there is a biholomorphism $f : \bar{Y} \to V$ where $V$ is either the unit disk, the complex plane or the Riemann sphere. Once this it known then $ \pi_1(Y) \subset Aut(\bar{Y})$ and $Y \cong V/G,G= f \pi_1(Y)f^{-1}$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution in great generality:

Let $X$ be a Riemann surface, $Y$ its universal cover, and $\pi:Y\rightarrow X$ the universal covering map. Let $\Sigma=\big\{\{U_i\},\{\varphi_j\}\big\}$ be the complex structure on $X$. Then, $\Sigma$ may be lifted to $Y$ by way of $\pi$ to induce a complex structure $\Sigma'=\big\{\{\pi^{-1}|_{U_i}\},\{\psi_j\equiv \varphi_j\circ\pi\}\big\}$ on $Y$.

Let $\mathscr{U}\subseteq Y$ open, then $\varphi\circ\pi\equiv \psi$ on $\mathscr{U}$, which is to say that the coordinate neighborhoods have been chosen so that $\pi\equiv id_{\mathbb{D}}$ locally. In this case, $\pi$ is certainly a local biholomorphism.

Let $\pi'$ be a covering induced by some distinct complex structure $\Sigma^\ast$ on $Y$, and take $\mathscr{U}$ as before. If it holds for each $\mathscr{U}$ that there is some biholomorphism $f$ so that $f\circ\varphi\circ\pi'\equiv \psi$ on $\mathscr{U}$, then $\pi'$ is a local biholomorphism.

This really just amounts to saying that any universal covering map $\pi$ which is locally biholomorphic must be intimately related with $\Sigma'$, the complex structure on $Y$ induced by $X$.